# Logarithm inequality from Rosen Discrete Mathematics 8.3 proof of divide and conquer Big O formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, logarithms, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

I'm confused why there is "$\le$" instead of "$<$" in the expression

> $(f(1) + c) + ck \le (f(1) + c) + c \cdot log_{b}n$

from the following portion of the proof

> When $n$ is not a power of $b$, we have $b^{k} < n < b^{k+1}$, for a positive integer $k$. Because $f$ is increasing, it follows that $f(n) \le f(b^{k+1}) = f(1) + c(k+1) = (f(1) + c) + ck \le (f(1) + c) + c \cdot log_{b}n$.

considering that $\mathbf{log(x)}$ is a monotonically increasing function.

 

 




 
In case it helps, I'm including the entire theorem and the beginning of the proof.

#### Theorem

> Let $f$ be an increasing function that satisfies the recurrence relation
>
> > $f(n)  = a f(n/b) + c$
>
> whenever $n$ is divisible by $b$, where $a \ge 1$, *b* is an integer greater than 1, and *c* is a positive real number. Then
>
> > $f(n)$ is 
> > $\left\{
> > \begin{array}{11}
> > O(n^{log_{b}a})\mbox{ if } a > 1 \\
> > O(log(n))  \mbox{ if } a = 1
> > \end{array}
> > \right.$
>
> Furthermore, when $n = b^{k}$ and $a \not= 1$, where *k* is a positive integer,
>
> > $f(n) = C_{1}n^{log_{b}a} + C_{2}$,
>
> where $C_{1} = f(1) + c / (a - 1)$ and $C_{2} = -c / (a - 1)$

#### Beginning of proof

First let $n = b^{k}$. From the expression for $f(n)$ obtained in the discussion preceding the theorem, with $g(n) = c$, we have

> $f(n) = a^{k}f(1) + \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} a^{j}c = a^{k}f(1) + c\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} a^{j}$.

When $a = 1$ we have

> $f(n) = f(1) + ck$.

Because $n = b^{k}$, we have $k = log_{b}n$. Hence

> $f(n) = f(1) + c \cdot log_{b}n$.

When $n$ is not a power of $b$, we have $b^{k} < n < b^{k+1}$, for a positive integer $k$. Because $f$ is increasing, it follows that $f(n) \le f(b^{k+1}) = f(1) + c(k+1) = (f(1) + c) + ck \le (f(1) + c) + c \cdot log_{b}n$.

Comment: Since $f$ is an increasing function we need to use $\le$. If it is monotonically increasing aka strictly increasing then we just use $<$